Do any Christian groups today have esoteric teachings about the Great Pyramid of Giza?
Charles Taze Russel, the founder of the 19th century Bible Students movement that eventually become the Jehovah's Witnesses, taught extensively that the Great Pyramid of Giza had esoteric meaning relevant to Christians and even that the Pyramid had been built under divine influence. The Jehovah's Witnesses no longer teach this, but do admit that the Great Pyramid may have been built using astrological lore that Christians should not have anything to do with. There has been some speculation that the Great Pyramid and/or the Pyramids in general were built by Joseph as grain silos, but this idea doesn't seem to be official teaching in any church.
Are there any Christian groups today, in the 21st century, that have specific teachings on the relevance of the Great Pyramid to Christians or believers in the Christian Bible? By specific teachings, I'm not referring to the belief that it exists (it obviously does), but that it has some esoteric or other special meaning that is not found in modern-day academic Egyptology. This would include, for example, teachings on any of the following:

That the Great Pyramid was built on divine command or by intervention of God or other creatures of God mentioned in the Bible such as angels or the Nephilim.
That the Great Pyramid was, or is, a temple to God (i.e. as opposed to a pagan deity or deified pagan ruler).
That the Great Pyramid had some specific relevance to the Old Testament Antediluvians, Patriarchs, or Israelites (e.g. that it was built by Adam, Seth, Enoch, Noah, Abraham, Joseph, or some other Biblical figure for some specific purpose that just happens to have not been made crystal clear in the extant Biblical texts).
That the Great Pyramid contains hidden messages for Christians.
That the Great Pyramid has some other specific relevance to ancient and/or modern believers beyond simply being a cool ancient building.

Discussion:
To be clear, I'm not asking for links to texts on 19th century or later Pyramidology or other forms of what is considered today to be fringe archaeology. Those are easy to find. Obviously, many Pyramidologists are and have been Christians, but I'm asking about churches that have formal teachings in the way that the Bible Students did, not about what individual Christians believe or believed. While I have read some of the works of Ron Wyatt, a famous fringe archaeologist and Seventh-Day Adventist who claimed to have made many fantastic discoveries in the Middle East, neither his findings nor his conclusions seem to have been accepted by any church, even his own. To make an analogy, there may well be a Christian artist out there who painted Methuselah as a ginger, but that doesn't mean that any Christian church, sect, community, order, or other type of group officially teaches that Methuselah was ginger or that his being ginger had any specific spiritual or doctrinal effect.
The reason why a particular church would have teachings on this would be interesting, but would not directly affect whether a teaching counts. The teaching could be based on any combination of Biblical exegesis, archaeology, ancient traditions or claims of ancient tradition, modern-day prophesy by or direct revelation to leaders (for churches that believe in such), or extra-Biblical or apocryphal texts.
Obviously science-fiction or fantasy stories that include mystical or fantastical teachings on the Pyramid or Egyptian pyramids in general, such as the Stargate franchise, are right out. Those are interesting stories but are not religion, even though they often reference religion or include religious content.

See: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/44927/do-any-christian-groups-believe-that-joseph-built-the-pyramids-to-store-grain-in

@DJClayworth I referenced that question in my OP. It has a different scope than mine. That question asks about the pyramids (plural) in general, but asks specifically about them being built by Joseph. I am asking about a single pyramid only (the one most commonly associated with Pyramidology in general and as it was present in the early Jehovah's Witnesses), but open to uses or meanings outside of just being Joseph's grain silos.
